# Is it possible to exclude/ignore certain CSS-files from the Sass Processor?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using SASS/SCSS. I have some .css-files which I want to be ignored  by the RubySassProcessor. Does anybody know how to exclude them?

Comment: I don't understand your question, you meean don't watch some sass files?

Comment: I have some css-files in my project which are creating errors. It's normal CSS but the SassProcessor doesn't like some IE workarounds. So I want these files to be ignored by the processor. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, just don't watch it or includes them in your sass file

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, because vanilla CSS is a subset of SCSS.

Answer (score 11):

If you add an underscore in front of the filename it will be ignored, but can then be added as a partial using @import.

1. Rename filename.scss to _filename.scss
2. Optional: Add the following to a file you want to include it in:

   @import "filename"

This will also effectively ignore the css file, since it will not be compiling changes from the scss file to the css file.

A deeper explanation can be seen here:
[Webstorm 6 - How to make the scss file watcher ignore files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905242/webstorm-6-how-to-make-the-scss-file-watcher-ignore-files)

And here in the Partials section:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Comment: Great, i just renamed the file.scss -> _file.scss and it works !

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this: Separate the `sass|scss` files and `css` into different directories and use `sass --watch` only on the `sass` folder. The output should be redirected into the `css` folder.

Assuming your app structure is something similar to:

```
app
|
|--assets
|----|
|----|--test.sass
|----|--print.sass
|----|--ie.css
```

Change the structure to:

```
app/
|
|--assets/
|----|---sass/
|----|----|--test.sass
|----|----|--print.sass
|----|---stylesheets/
|----|----|--ie.css
```

and run

```
sass --watch assets/sass:assets/stylesheets
```