# Webstorm 6 - How to make the scss file watcher ignore files

Tags: sass, webstorm

I would like the file watcher for SCSS files to ignore files with file names starting with an underscore, for example _buttons.scss.

How would I do that?

Comment: Every file watcher has **"Scope" field** -- just create a scope that would exclude all unwanted files.

Comment: From the docs: If you have a SCSS or Sass file ... but don’t want to compile to a CSS file, you can add an underscore to the beginning of the filename. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by adding a _ to a file that you want to be ignored... Done! From the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html):

> Partials
>
> If you have a SCSS or Sass file that you want to import but don’t want
>   to compile to a CSS file, you can add an underscore to the beginning
>   of the filename. This will tell Sass not to compile it to a normal CSS
>   file. You can then import these files without using the underscore.
>
> For example, you might have _colors.scss. Then no _colors.css file
>   would be created, and you can do
>
> @import "colors";

So adding an underscore will do the job. Just don't import.

Be careful naming your files because if you have a `style.scss` and `_style.scss` Sass will see these as the same filename and trow an error:

```
>>> Change detected to: /Users/allcaps/test/style.scss
WARNING: In /Users/allcaps/test:
  There are multiple files that match the name "style.scss":
    _style.scss
    style.scss
```

A simple workaround will be to add two underscores: `__style.scss`.

Comment: Thanks. Weird cause I was getting my file with an underscore compiled to css, but I reckon it might have been because it wasn't being imported yet.

Comment: Same thing happened to me just now using the Sass file watcher in PhpStorm 6.

Comment: I also had a similar issue. If I created _example.scss before including it in style.scss, it was automatically compiled to _example.css. But if I imported it first, then created the file, I didn't have that issue. Now I basically just delete the underscored CSS files if they show up since after I import them they don't compile again. Slightly frustrating, but not really a huge deal.

Answer (score 1):

@LazyOne has the right idea. A `Scope` can be created that excludes files that being with an underscore (_). The page at http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/scopes.html#d437174e402 has more information about this, but basically you select the folder you want after creating a custom scope and then in the scope field append it again with && ! between the two and exclude files starting with an underscore.

For example:

```
file:website/css//* && !file:website/css//_*
```