# Middleman: Include a .scss file in the build, but do not compile it

Tags: ruby, sass, middleman

When running the `middleman build` command, all the stylesheet files specified in the `set :css_dir` are compiled to `.css` extensions.

**My question is:** How can I exclude a `.scss` file from the compilation process (so that the content remains the same and doesn't compile to CSS), but can it be available in the build directory after `middleman build`?

---

A question was raised whether it's similar to ignoring the `.scss` files in Compass compilation: It's similar in nature, but unlike that process, which is more along the line of "ignore this file during the compilation", this question is specific to middleman, which is "ignore this file during the compilation, but do not ignore it during the build process".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to exclude/ignore certain CSS-files from the Sass Processor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584729/is-it-possible-to-exclude-ignore-certain-css-files-from-the-sass-processor)

Comment: @cimmanon it's similar in nature, but unlike that question, which is more along the line of "ignore this file during the compilation", this question is specific to middleman, which is "ignore this file during the compilation, but do not ignore it during the build process"

Answer (score 1):

Yoy may use the `_underscore` prefix to exclude files from Sass compilation. It's intended for usage with includes/partials, but will do the job. Sass won't compile those files until you @include them.

After that, simply copy the needed files to your build directory. The  `:after_build` hook should be the right place for that:

https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom_extensions/#after_build